# Locating elements using wildcards in Xpath

Tags: xpath, xpath-2.0

I have a table with dynamically generated rows that have ids like the following

```
id='cu1111-co23466-t1-a23456'
id='cu1111-co23466-t2-a3246'
id='cu1111-co23466-t3-a265873'
id='cu1111-co23466-t3-a0985'
id='cu1111-co23466-t2-a3274'
```

How can I select multiple `<tr>` elements using wildcards? Say I wish to select all `<tr>` elements that have `cu1111-co-23466-t2` in their id... I wish to do something like..

```
//*[@id='cu1111-co23466-t2-a*']
```

But its not selecting any rows. I am using the Developer Tools Console in Chrome to do the check. It gives me error:

```
Error: INVALID_EXPRESSION_ERR: DOM XPath Exception 51
```

I think I have XPath 1.0 . Is there any way to check what version I have and how to upgrade it?

Answer (score 2):

If the wildcard isn't in a middle of the string, you can try

```
//@id[contains(., 'cu1111-co23466-t2-a')]
```

You might also use the `starts-with` function.

Comment: Well, the wildcard can be in the middle of the string. You would only need another `contains` with `and` concatenation. To distinguish which one came first, you would need to mix `start-with` and `contains`.